# How can I stop AVERAGEIF formula returning #DIV/0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, average, error-correction

I have the following formula returning #DIV/0! when all 5 cells are blank:

```
=AVERAGEIF(CV17:CV21,">0")
```

[Spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOKob.png)

This is being used to average call time over the period of a 5 day working week so I am using the AVERAGEIF function to only count cells that I enter a time into. The formula is in cell CV24.

As I want another cell to calculate the rolling average over a year I need CV24 to display 0 if no times are entered for the entire week.

I have attempted to use the IFERROR as such:

```
AVERAGEIF(CV17:CV21,">0",IFERROR(CV17:CV21,0))
```

This is telling me I have typed an incorrect formula.

I also tried `=IFERROR(CV10:CV14,0)` which returned 0 when times were entered.

I feel like I'm close but my understanding of formulas isn't great. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `AVERAGEIF(CV17:CV21,">0",IFERROR(CV17:CV21,0))`

This is your formula

```
IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(CV17:CV21,">0",CV17:CV21),0)
```

This is the correct use of the IFERROR formula.

Comment: Thank you Serkan, this has worked a treat!